# Validation is not work ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Login View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.usename, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.usename, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

My model:

```
[DisplayName("Tên đăng nhập")]
[Remote("CheckUsername", "Admin", "Admin")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Tên đăng nhập không bỏ trống!")]
public string usename { get; set; }
```

My controller:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

When I click submit button then validation isn't working.
I don't know where my problem?

Comment: Most likely you didn't add the validation JavaScript to your page.

Comment: Thanks you. I try add jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js script then working.

Answer (score 0):

1) You forget validation summary in razor page:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

The model are displayed using the `validationsummary()`.
The bool property indicates if you would like to display the validation summary error messages at the same time as displaying the property error messages. If you choose not to then the property error messages will be displayed to the user first. Then, when the user has resolved all of those error messages, the summary error messages will be displayed after.

If the bool parameter is true then only model-level errors are displayed. If the parameter is false then all errors are shown.

2) Check jQuery validation libraries in your project. If there is missing validation script try to install by Nuget:

```
Install-Package jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive -Version xx.xxxx
```